# XAML parser error: The TypeConverter for "MyType" does not support converting from a string

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight-5.0

But it does.  I have created a type converter that implements CanConvertFrom(), defined the type converter on type type.  Everything runs fine.  This is just XAML that defines design time data for Blend, but the error is very annoying.

It appears that VS is just not trying to use the type converter.  Is there some place that you have to register type converters so that they will be used at design time by Visual Studio?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeTypeConverter))]
[DataContract]
public struct MyType
{
    [DataMember]
    internal readonly float _Value;

    public MyType(float value)
    {
        _Value = (float)Math.Round(value, 3);
    }
}

public class MyTypeTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(String))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            float f;
            if (!Single.TryParse((string)value, out f))
                return null;
            return new MyType(f);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            return true;
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return ((MyType)value).ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```